# Jquery $.ajax sending Chinese character does not retrieve correctly in Spring Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, utf-8

I want to pass some Chinese character with jquery $.ajax to Spring Controller but when I print  the param value in Spring controller  I am getting wrong value.

This is ajax code:

```
var edit = 'editGroup?groupID='+groupID+'&groupName='+groupName+'&description='+description+'&status='+status+'&json='+json;
        if(groupName ==""){
            alert("Group Name can not be Empty!");
            return;
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:edit,
            contentType: "charset=utf-8",
            success:function(result){
                //window.location ="<c:url value='viewGroupListByUser'/>";
            }
        });
```

This is code in Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="editGroup", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Integer editGroup(@RequestParam(value="groupID") Integer groupID, 
            @RequestParam(value="groupName") String name, @RequestParam(value="description") String description, 
            @RequestParam(value="status") String status, @RequestParam(value="json") String json)
            throws ServletException, IOException, JSONException {
        System.out.println("Name : "+name); 
...
```

I have configured web.xml as :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have tried a lot to fix the problem referred this [Answer @ this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170496/problems-with-utf-8-encoding-jsp-jquery-spring), but still I could not get Chinese character in Controller with ajax. Please help me out, I am stuck here, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the post method but put the data in the url pass the data as the data parameter in the ajax call.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'editGroup',
        data:{
            groupID:groupID,
            groupName:groupName,
            description:description,
            status:status,
            json:json
        },
        success:function(result){
            //window.location ="<c:url value='viewGroupListByUser'/>";
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for response but now I am getting 開冷氣會有病 value as ?????? in Spring Controller, any suggestion please ?

Comment: it would have been better if you could share how you fixed it. Your problem is resolved an you ran away...:-)