# What happens to the jsp page not supporting utf8 characters for html text field

Tags: jsp, utf-8, meta, html4

I am using the following code to support UTF-8 in jsp. Please look at this :

JSP Code :
**editDistList.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

But when response is sent over the server with the post parameter (see the screenshots below), the value is not save in UTF-8 for that particular text and it displays other characters. I am using ***αβγδεζηθ*** characters (taken help from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script_charset ) but it displays Î±Î²Î³Î´ÎµÎ¶Î·Î¸in "ISO-8859-1".

[image]

[image]

I don't know why i am getting the garbage characters. I need to get UTF-8 characters which i have entered in text field somewhere. The static text displayed on same jsp page are displayed well. I used native2ascii to convert those characters to unicode-escape characters. But the problem is with dynamic text.

Please help..

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170496/problems-with-utf-8-encoding-jsp-jquery-spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You insert**

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

into `<head></head>` pair tags.

**Or you use this template for *.jsp files:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
<%--Contents--%>
</body>

</html>
```